# Загрузка Hex файла в микроконтроллер

Tags: c#, c++, c, микроконтроллеры, hex

Работаю с опытным образцом микроконтроллера, поэтому программами типа Flash- magic заливать не получается. Фирма- создатель прислала кривую- косую прогу для заливки прошивки, поэтому написал свою. В итоге, столкнулся с проблемой- не могу загрузить Hex- файл в МК.
Сделал .bin файл по алгоритму "Из каждой строки Hex- файла вычленить поле с данными и по 2 символа перевести этой в тип данных byte со смещением (Работает правильно, проверил, сверяя с онлайн конвертером). Все эти данные засунул в байтовый массив". Этот массив записал в ОЗУ МК, но результата нет.
Вот скрин .bin файла, открытого в программе HxD: 
[image: Получившийся файл, открытый в программе HxD]
У кого есть опыт в этом деле, может подсказать? Желательно на языке семейства C. Спасибо

Comment: А вам нужен код программы, когда вопрос был в том, чтобы мне скинули кусок кода, отвечающий конкретно за разбивку Hex- файла и забросом его в массив для последующей выгрузки? Ошибка заключается в том, что ее нет- МК после загрузки у меня просто не отвечает ничего. Просто нет ответа. Поэтому и такая формулировка.

Comment: Формат HEX-файла с прошивкой описан, в чем вопрос?

Comment: У вас скорее всего неправильно данные преобразованы в бинарный формат. У вас получился текст из десятичных чисел в ascii-подобной кодировке (видно по правому столбцу на снимке). Если бы это был бинарный формат, а не текстовый - правый столбец состоял бы из пропусков и бессмысленного (для человека) набора символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формат Intel Hexadecimal object file содержит шестнадцатеричный код, представленный в текстовом виде. В нём содержится не только исполняемый код, но и контрольные данные. Описание формата приведено [здесь](http://www.interlog.com/~speff/usefulinfo/Hexfrmt.pdf). Есть описание на русском языке [здесь](http://microsin.net/programming/pc/intel-hex-file-format.html).

Альтернативный вариант - файл hex можно перевести в bin с помощью сторонних программ, например, [hex2bin](http://hex2bin.sourceforge.net).

---

UPD. Когда у вас есть bin-файл, вопросов быть не должно. Нужно просто брать из него байт за байтом (или слово за словом, в зависимости от архитектуры и отладочного протокола) и передавать его в контроллер.

В hex-файле шестнадцатеричные данные представлены в текстовом виде. Символы конца строки здесь являются частью формата файла, но не являются частью исполняемого кода. Вам нужно читать этот файл построчно, извлекать из неё контрольную информацию и исполняемый код. Например, каждая строка содержит количество байт для записи, смещение, тип записи, сам исполняемый код, байт контрольной суммы. Извлекаете из строки исполняемый код и записываете его в память контроллера.

Насчёт младшим байтом вперёд. Здесь имеется в виду порядок байт в машинном слове. Размер машинного слова зависит от архитектуры вашего контроллера, но обычно это 32 бита (4 байта). Скорее всего, вам нужно передавать байты с конца в пределах каждого слова. Например, у вас есть такой массив байт:

```
12 aa 55 88 bb 77 ee 66 55 22 77 dd 6d 45 9a 32
```

Его нужно передавать следующим образом:

```
88 55 aa 12 66 ee 77 bb dd 77 22 55 32 9a 45 6d
```

При этом проверьте настройки компилятора: он может уже генерировать файл с порядком байт, который нужен вашему контроллеру. Подробнее о порядке байт можно поискать по запросам Endianness, Big endian, Little endian.

p.s. Обновил ссылку на русскоязычное описание.

Comment: А дальше просто записать бинарник на МК?

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov, да, именно так.

Comment: А если именно Hex писать, то надо подавать его со всеми символами, включая CR LF? И еще такой момент- в дадашите написано, что надо подавать массив младшим байтом вперед, это, выходит, мне надо с конца файла начинать?

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov, обновил ответ.

Comment: Ну, я взял из каждой строчки поле с данными, попарно их перевел в байтовый вид, по итогу у меня получился .bin файл, но МК все равно не принимает его. Этот бинарник я открыл программой HxD, он спокойно его читает. К посту прикреплю картинку

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov, что характерно, HxD спокойно читает вообще любой файл. Так что это не показатель того, что вы правильно выполнили преобразование.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема Решил её подключением к нужным выходам микроконтроллера КВАРЦЕВЫЙ резонатор, и о чудо, прошился. А можно поинтересоваться что вы использовали при написании приложения по загрузке скетча в микроконтроллер